# Regex to extract UUID without key value in json

Tags: json, regex, http, jmeter, request

I have below json from which I wants to extract  '07199fca-b43f-4e58-b0fc-c1e254f34ac0' values. I got with multiple regex available in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but every time I get all UUID value any way by which I get Unique value that has no json key assign.

JSON Syntax:

```
    [
  [      
    {
      "clientId": 178,      
      "uniqueId": "5f7f919f-7e0f-4a1e-9a91-89b673896da6",
      "displayName": "Automation Client Test",      
      "productVersion": "7.9.0.0"
    },
    {
      "clientId": 1206,      
      "uniqueId": "096b3549-6899-4621-854c-e682aeb543bd",
      "displayName": "TestClient1",
      "productVersion": "7.9.0.0"
    },
    {
      "clientId": 1356,
      "uniqueId": "faad0e20-dd29-4146-8a8f-37648749aa4e",
      "displayName": "Client Automation",
      "productVersion": "7.9.0.0"
    }
  ], 
  "07199fca-b43f-4e58-b0fc-c1e254f34ac0"
]
```

Comment: Please post the regex you're using.

Comment: You can only use a regex to extract data from a JSON document if the JSON document's structure will be consistent - otherwise it's (provably mathematically) impossible to accomplish. Is there a reason you're not using a JSON library?

Comment: I m using '[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}' regex but it gives 'uniqueId' value also but I do not requires that..                                                I have to use Regex extractor to get this value. I can go with JSR223 script but I wants to make my jmeter script simple

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not 100% clear what you are looking for, but *if* you are looking for the last element of the list that also satisfies `[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}` regex (with quotes around it), then:

```
(?:['"])([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})(?:['"]\s*]\s*$)
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiToYW/3/)

1. `(?:['"])` Matches `'` or `"`.
2. `([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})` Your regex captured in capture group 1.
3. `(?:['"]\s*]\s*$)` Matches `'` or `"` followed by 0 or more white space characters followed by a `]` followed by 0 or more white space characters followed by the end of string.

The code:

```
import re

s = """    [
  [
    {
      "clientId": 178,
      "uniqueId": "5f7f919f-7e0f-4a1e-9a91-89b673896da6",
      "displayName": "Automation Client Test",
      "productVersion": "7.9.0.0"
    },
    {
      "clientId": 1206,
      "uniqueId": "096b3549-6899-4621-854c-e682aeb543bd",
      "displayName": "TestClient1",
      "productVersion": "7.9.0.0"
    },
    {
      "clientId": 1356,
      "uniqueId": "faad0e20-dd29-4146-8a8f-37648749aa4e",
      "displayName": "Client Automation",
      "productVersion": "7.9.0.0"
    }
  ],
  "07199fca-b43f-4e58-b0fc-c1e254f34ac0"
]"""

m = re.search(r"""(?:['"])([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})(?:['"]\s*]\s*$)""", s, flags=re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    print(m[1])
```

Prints:

```
07199fca-b43f-4e58-b0fc-c1e254f34ac0
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is a well-structured data, using regular expressions for parsing JSON is not the best idea, I would rather recommend going for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead

The relevant [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as `$[1]`

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)